# Progress<T> buffering for WPF updates

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, buffering, tpl-dataflow

I have a method that takes `Progress<T>` as a parameter and internally reports progress on it.

Because the progress could happen rapidly (e.g. hundreds of times per second) on a worker thread, I need to buffer it and then update the view-model with the records received, e.g. every half a second.

In the past I've used `Observable.FromEventPattern().Buffer(TimeSpan)` so I see that it's possible to utilize the same Rx mechanism if I wrap the `Progress<T>` reporting into an event. However that would seem like an overkill. Is there a  more elegant solution?

I've also looked at TPL Dataflow's `BufferBlock` but I'm not sure if it supports time-based buffering, e.g. every half a second.

If anyone has an example, please post it. It'll be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `BufferBlock` doesn't have any support for that. You could use `BatchBlock` and call [`TriggerBatch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160310) from a timer, but I think Rx is a better choice here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Went with Rx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RX is the obvious choice for doing this however you don't "need" to use events at all to use RX, in your case you could simply use a `Subject<Progress<T>>` and have your method (that currently gets the `Progress<T>` as a parameter) push the data into the subject. Then you'd have your RX query on the subject just like your previous did on your event sourced observable

[`Subject<T>` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229173)

However if you feel better about doing it with an event the way you're used to, i see nothing overkill about it at all.

Comment: If you post your actual current code i'll be happy to edit this post by adding it as a sample rewritten with subject